# How to fetch data from Firebase Database with react native? (Warining: Error: child failed: path argument was an invalid path)

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a managed workflow expo project (Javascript 9) where I want to read my data from Firebase database. I succesfully managed to implement firestore but the database is giving me rough times.

This is my code to Fecth the data:

```
export const fetchEmployees = async () => {
  const rootRef = await dbref(db_realtime,"Employees");
  const query = get(query(child(rootRef))).then((result) =>{
    console.log(result)
  })
}
```

This is the warning I get:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: child failed: path argument was
> an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and
> can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"]

And this is how the data looks like in my Firebase Database storage:

[image]

Comment: try with path ``/`` or ``/Employees``.

Comment: @AnyamBorogass try with path Employees/

Comment: export const fetchEmployees = async () => {
  const rootRef = await dbref(db_realtime,"/Employees");
  const query = get(query(child(rootRef))).then((result) =>{
    console.log(result)
  })
}  Got same warning.. :/ (tried: "/Employees", "/", "Employees/")

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example will help you. It will return all employees details -

```
const getdata = await db.ref('Employees').once('value',function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val)
}
```

Here db is your firebase.database().

If it's not working use 'Employees/'.

EDITED -

For 9 -

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
const employeeRef = ref(db, 'Employees');
onValue(employeeRef , (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this is for Javascript 8 and I am using version 9

Comment: Check edited answer.

Comment: With this I get the following error: "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'path.pieceNum_')]" :(((

Comment: onvalue() is better than get(). According to documentation, get() can increase bandwidth also generates error if cannot get value from server.